# A basic confusion regarding convergence of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I think $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n -y_n =0$ does not imply that both the sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ converge to the same value. If one converge them the other converge to the same value due to triangle inequality. Is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Indeed. Another way to put this is that the sequences converge to the same limit or not at all.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequences $x_n=y_n=n$. Clearly your limit holds but neither sequence converges. As you said though, if one sequence converges then both converge to the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes...Let us consider the sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$, where $x_n=n$ and $y_n=n+\dfrac{1}{n}$. Here $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(x_n-y_n)=0$, but both the sequences do not converge.

Answer (score 0):

Yes more specifically the Reverse Triangle Inequality.

$\text{lim}_{n \rightarrow \infty}(x_{n} - y_{n}) = 0$ implies $||x_{n} - y_{n}|| \rightarrow 0$ then $| |x_{n}| - |y_{n}| | \leq |x_{n} - y_{n}| \rightarrow 0$ 
$\\ \therefore |\text{ } |x_{n}| - | y_{n}|\text{ } | \rightarrow 0 $ $\therefore|x_{n}| - |y_{n}| \rightarrow 0$. Since we know that for convergent sequences the absolute value of the sequences converge as well. We can see that the last limit only holds if both $x_{n}$ and $y_{n}$ converge to the same limit.